# Sequelize: column name to lowercase not working with included models

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have two models: Category and Bookmark. Bookmark is associated with category through categoryId column.

Category also have `name`, `createdAt`, `orderId` columns;

---

I can get category and all its bookmarks with:

```js
const category = await Category.findOne({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    include: [
      {
        model: Bookmark,
        as: 'bookmarks'
      },
    ]
  });
```

---

**But now** I want to change how bookmarks are ordered. Order type can be `name`, `createdAt` or `orderId`;

```js
const order = orderType == 'name'
  ? [[
      { model: Bookmark, as: 'bookmarks' },
      Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('bookmarks.name')),
      'ASC'
    ]]
  : [[{ model: Bookmark, as: 'bookmarks' }, orderType, 'ASC']]

const category = await Category.findOne({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    include: [
      {
        model: Bookmark,
        as: 'bookmarks'
      },
    ],
    order
  });
```

It works fine when orderType is `createdAt` or `orderId` but fails when it's `name`

---

I'm getting this error: `SQLITE_ERROR: near \"(\": syntax error` and SQL query generated by Sequelize is:

```
SELECT `Category`.`id`, `Category`.`name`, `bookmarks`.`id` AS `bookmarks.id`, `bookmarks`.`name` AS `bookmarks.name`, `bookmarks`.`categoryId` AS `bookmarks.categoryId`, `bookmarks`.`orderId` AS `bookmarks.orderId`, `bookmarks`.`createdAt` AS `bookmarks.createdAt`
FROM `categories` AS `Category`
INNER JOIN `bookmarks` AS `bookmarks` ON `Category`.`id` = `bookmarks`.`categoryId`
ORDER BY `bookmarks`.lower(`bookmarks`.`name`) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed it to:

```js
const order =
    orderType == 'name'
      ? [[Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('bookmarks.name')), 'ASC']]
      : [[{ model: Bookmark, as: 'bookmarks' }, orderType, 'ASC']];
```

and now it's working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).